# Is it possible to split a full name selected in a dropdown list and save it into 2 separate columns as first name and last name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, getter-setter

I have the following columns in Entity Framework Code first approach:

```
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And I combine them into a full name:

```
 public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + " " + FirstName; }
    }
```

I don't even know if it's possible, but how I can generate a setter for this in order to send the values from the fullname to the other 2 columns when selecting it from e.g a dropdown list?

Comment: Do you have a space in between first name and last name?

Comment: You should not expose Entities to UI layer. Instead, you want to transfer to View Model or DTO - data transfer object.

Comment: What if the first and/or last name contains a space? Better to use a comma as a delimiter than a space.

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

The simpler approach would be to split on the first space you see, but it would break if anyone has a first or last name with a space in it. Broken first-names are rare, but last-names with spaces are common, e.g. "Jean-Claude Van Damme".

```
 public String FullName {
     set {
         Int32 spaceIdx = value.IndexOf(" ");
         if( spaceIdx == -1 ) {
             this.FirstName = value;
             this.LastName  = "";
         }
         else
         {
             this.FirstName = value.Substring(0, spaceIdx);
             this.LastName  = value.Substring(spaceIdx + 1);
         }
     }
 }
```

A better approach is to identify the names uniquely in your system and use that from your name-dropdown. Assuming this is ASP.NET MVC:

```
public class YourViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; }
    public Int32 SelectedNameByPersonId { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public IActionResult YourAction() {

    List<SelectListItem> names = db.People.Select( dbPerson => new SelectListItem() {
        Text = dbPerson.FirstName + " " + dbPerson.LastName,
        Value = dbPerson.Id.ToString()
    } ).ToList(); // ToList so the DB is only queried once

    return this.View( new YourViewModel() { Names = names } );
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult YourAction(YourViewModel model) {

    DBPerson dbPerson = db.People.GetPerson( model.SelectedNameByPersonId );
    // do stuff with person
}
```

In your view (aspx syntax):

```
<%= Html.DropDownFor( m => m.SelectNameByPersonId, this.Model.Names ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you would do a FullName.Split(' '); getting an array of names. It's all good when first and last names are single word. But how about John Billy Doe? Where does the LastName end and the FirstName begin?

Instead, you could use a different separator, like a comma: John, Billy Doe.
That way, doing a FullName.Split(','); would yield the correct Last Name and First Name.

```
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
         return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
    }
    set
    {
         string[] names = value.Split(", ");
         LastName = names[0];
         FirstName = names[1];
    }
}
```

EDIT: Of course, some validation is required for the value, but it's pretty hard to type code on the Android app (as I am doing). So, unless you need help with that, I leave it up to you.

Comment: This is the best answer, best approach, with a bit of validation, would be just perfect

Answer (score 0):

I have tried for some workaround. Please try this and let me know of it works.

```
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] //This will make sure that entity framework will not map this to a new column
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + " " + FirstName; }
        // Here comes your desired setter method.
        set
        {
            string[] str = value.Split(' ');
            if (str.Length == 2)
            {
                FirstName = str[1];
                LastName = str[0];
            }
            else if (str.Length >= 0 && value.Length > 0)
            {
                LastName = str[0];
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Invalid name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that will work as long as FullName isn't used in a database query.

Comment: The `FullName` property should be marked with `[NotMapped]` and you should handle the case where the length of the array is more than 2. For example you can throw an exception, or decide to put everything in the first name except for the last word.

Comment: @user3399858 : You can customize setter as per your need and cases.

Comment: `str.Length >= 0` should be changed to `str.Length > 0` because if `str.Length` is zero then `str[0]` will throw an exception.

Comment: No, actaully if `str.Length` is Zero then `value.Length` will also be Zero and it will not enter that block

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I think this might help(plus input error handling).

```
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return LastName + " " FirstName;
    }

    series
    {
        var nameParts = value.Split(' ');
        LastName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameParts[0]) ? string.Empty : nameParts[0];
        FirstName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameParts[1]) ? string.Empty : nameParts[1];
    }
}
```